# How to interpolate variable into firebase snapshot?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using firebase functions to send users a notification. I can user string interpolation like so:

```
      const original = change.after.val();
      const lover = context.auth.uid;

      const recipient_username = original.username;
      const topic = `${recipient_username}_notifications`;
```

But now I need to make a database call to get the username from the user_id, and use the username to get the value of loves form the 'original' snapshot, but this does not work:

```
return db.ref('/users/' + lover).once('value', (snapshot) =>  {

          var username = snapshot.val().username;
          var love = original.loves.username // I need this to use the variable username, but it is just saying "username"

          console.log("lover username")
          console.log(username)
          console.log("loves")
          console.log(loves)

          const payload = {
            notification:{
              title: "You've got Love!",
              body: `${username} sent you Love! Refresh your inbox to recieve it, and why not send some back!`
            }
          };
```

How can I change `var love = original.loves.username` to be something like: `var love = original.loves.${username}`?

The database looks like this:

```
   users/
         username: usernamehere
         love/
               otherusername: 10 // the amount of love they sent.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called `.val()` on the `original` turning this into a Javascript object.

Traversing paths in Javascript objects can be done with the `.loves` helper functions or using string lookups. Try the following

```
var username = snapshot.val().username;
var love = original.loves[username];
```